# NServicebus failing to forward failed message to error queue

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I am running into issues with forwarding failed messages to error queue as ISendMessages was not configured.

I have the following sections in my app.config file

```
<section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />

<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="nservicebus_error" />

<add key="ConnectivityRetryPeriod" value="30" />
<add key="FatalRetryCount" value="2" />
<add key="RetryFrequency" value="2" />
```

However, when the FatalRetryCount is exceeded, I get the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=Could not forward failed message to error queue, reason: System.ArgumentException: NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.ISendMessages has not been configured. In order to avoid this exception, check the return value of the 'HasComponent' method for this type.
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Spring.SpringObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.IContainer.Build(Type typeToBuild)
   at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.CommonObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IBuilder.Build[T]()
   at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, String reason).
  Source=NServiceBus.Core
  StackTrace:
       at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, String reason)
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       Message=NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.ISendMessages has not been configured. In order to avoid this exception, check the return value of the 'HasComponent' method for this type.
       Source=NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Spring
       StackTrace:
            at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Spring.SpringObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.IContainer.Build(Type typeToBuild)
            at NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Common.CommonObjectBuilder.NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.IBuilder.Build[T]()
            at NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder.FaultManager.SendFailureMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e, String reason)
```

In specific, this exception is logged in the following lien in the FaultManager.cs in the `NServiceBus.Faults.Forwarder` namespace

[image: Line where the error is thrown]

Here is the App.Config section and the Config code that I use

[image: App.Config sections]

[image: Config code]

Comment: Can you post your endpoint config code?

Comment: I have updated the post with the config code

Comment: I think Adam means the "Configure.With()..." code in, what is typically named, EndpointConfig.cs.

Comment: Thanks Adam & Kijana - I have updated the post with the config code

Comment: Could you try being explicit and adding ".SpringFrameworkBuilder()" and "MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaults()" to you endpoint config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix to this issue from the NServiceBus support team and it looks like the ISendMessages gets registered when I explicitly call .MsmqTransport(). I updated the config code to call .MsmqTransport() and FaultManager stopped throwing this exception